# Delete duplicate rows from temp table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the below columns

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| AssID | QuestionID | AnswerText |
+-------+------------+------------+
|    12 |         34 | Null       |
|    12 |         34 | Sample     |
|    13 |         35 | null       |
|    13 |         35 | test1      |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

I need to remove answertext null row with same AssId and QuestionID 
Final Output needs to be in this format

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| AssId | QuestionID | AnswerText |
+-------+------------+------------+
|    12 |         34 | Sample     |
|    13 |         35 | test1      |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

Please  help me with the delete query

Thanks in advance
Sree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cte and row_number to delete

```
;with cte as (
    select *, RowN = Row_number() over (partition by assid, questionid order by answertext) from yourtable
    )--or order by your id because you have not provided logic for which one to select in answertext
delete from cte where RowN > 1
```

Comment: if you order by answertext, you will delete the non null values and leave the null ones.. the opposite of what the expected output is supposedly

Comment: Yep for that you need to do order by any rowid which actually defines your output. I mentioned that in comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use exist to see if the NULL answerText row also has a Non-Null answerText Row

```
DELETE t
FROM MyTABLE t
WHERE  t.AnswerText IS NULL
       AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM   MyTable m
    WHERE  m.AssID = t.AssID
           AND m.QuestionID = t.QuestionID
           AND m.AnswerText IS NOT NULL
)
```